# Sequentially translate strings in a Transport Request/Task

Tags: translation, abap, transport

I've coded a few ABAP programs and created a some messages in a custom message class, they are under an specific Transport Request/Task.
I need to translate all translatable strings (Messages, Text Symbols, Selection Texts, etc) of the objects found in that Transport Request/Task.

Is there any tool (transaction, program, etc) to sequentially translate all those strings without manually exploring the objects one by one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [translation worklist](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_NW04/helpdata/en/77/571a1f492011d1894a0000e829fbbd/frameset.htm). It might be sensible to group the objects to be translated into separate packages for this - this also facilitates packaging and delivery of later versions.

Comment: [Translating Objects Directly](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw04/helpdata/en/41/71601b3ab0f34a8e00aa01338c68f3/content.htm): `It is possible to call up an individual object in transaction SE63 in order to translate it, without calling up a worklist.   Although we recommend that you translate objects via a worklist, you may need to translate an object directly in the following situations:   * The system in which the translation is required is not set up for translation.` I think this system doesn't have translation configured, and since i'm a external ABAPER, i won't be able to use worklists.

Comment: I'll approve your answer anyways, because it seems to be the correct tool to use for this kind of job.

Answer (score 3):

You can use tcode SE63 in order to translate your messages, programs, screens basically everything.

For example you can use this path in order to translate your text elements in an ABAP program:

> se63 -> Translation -> ABAP Objects -> Short Texts -> ABAP Texts ->
>   REPT Text Elements.

Write down your program's name and its main language and the target language. Go for it.

Hope it was helpful.

Talha

Comment: I've tried that, actually, that's what i used to translate my last requirement, but I had to list each program, screen and message class one by one, it's not only time consuming but error-prone. I'd to know if there's any way to automatically gather all strings from all objects in a specific transport request (if exist, i bet it does). Anyways, good answer, that tool was specially useful to sequentially translate all strings in my message classes.